# Enforce input greater than or equal to 0 and less than 24

Tags: c, do-while, boolean-expression

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main ()
{
int n,a=0,b=24;
do
  {
    scanf("%d",n); //ask the user to enter a value of n less than 24 
                  // but greater than 0. 
  } while(/*boolean expression logic*/)

if(a<n<b)
    {
    printf("%d\n",n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I need to evaluate:

> If the value of **n** is greater than or equal to 0 and less than 24 (less than or equal to 23) then
>
> .... go to the if statement and print the value of **n**
>
> otherwise
>
> ... ask the user to input the value of **n** i.e. it should again go back in the loop.

Comment: so what do you think the answer should be?

Comment: i know that it will be the opposite of  a<=n<b  (a=0,b=24), but i am not able to implement it in c.

Comment: 'i know that it will be the opposite' yes, so... while  (n<0) OR (n>23) loop again.  Now Google 'C boolean operators' and/or 'C boolean expressions', and do the coding.

Comment: A note for any C novices reading this post in the future:  **Never** use the expression format `(a < n < b)`.  Consider it invalid C.  It does **not** do what it looks like it should do.  Instead, always separate it out into the two checks you actually intend:  `((n > a) && (n < b))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the program to keep asking for values until `n>=0 && n<24`; in other words, you want to keep asking for values while `!(n>=0 && n<24)`, which using [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) we can write as `!(n>=0) || !(n<24)`, which can be reduced to `n<0 || n>=24`

```
do
{
    scanf("%d",n);
}
while(n<0 || n>=24)
```